# android LocalBroadcastManager and serialization

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I understand that while android allows `Serializable` objects to be passed within `Intent`s, it's not recommended for performance reasons.

however, if one is using `LocalBroadcastManager`, does the object ever get serialized, or parceled at all when passed in an intent? since LBM is not inter-process, there'd be no reason to invoke serialization (or parceling for that matter).

Answer (score 2):

You are right, there should be no reason to invoke serialization or parceling when using `LocalBroadcastManager`, however, that class was designed as a replacement for the normal `BroadcastManager` in cases in which sending a broadcast through the system made no sense; I think the idea was to make it possible for devs to replace normal broadcast with local ones w/out too much effort.

If you are working on a new project and need this kind of functionality, I would recommend to use a bus library like **[Otto](http://square.github.com/otto/)** or **[EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)**, which solves the same problem in a better, more elegant way (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at LocalBroadcastManager's source-code would suggest that Serializable/Parcelable objects in Intents are not serialized or parceled.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.java

Comment: So it is only available through the support compatibility package?  What about apps that have a minSDK of 14?